# Is "thinks I" in Melville's Moby-Dick used in the sense of "thought I"?

Tags: meaning, past-tense, narration

The following is just one of the examples of ***thinks I*** being used by Melville:

> When, at last, his mind seemed made up touching the character of his bedfellow, and he became, as it were, reconciled to the fact; he jumped out upon the floor, and by certain signs and sounds gave me to understand that, if it pleased me, he would dress first and then leave me to dress afterwards, leaving the whole apartment to myself. **Thinks I**, Queequeg, under the circumstances, this is a very civilized overture; but, the truth is, these savages have an innate sense of delicacy, say what you will; it is marvellous how essentially polite they are.

***Thinks I*** occurs thirteen times, whereas ***thought I*** occurs thirty seven times in [the novel.](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2701) Methinks the phrase is used by Melville in the meaning of ***thought I***. What puts me in doubt, though, is the lack of definitions of such meaning in dictionaries and the lack of any discussion in the Web, e.g. at ESE. I intend to edit [Wiktionary's entry on ***thinks***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thinks) as soon as I learn from you all..

Comment: *Thinks I* doesn't mean *thought I*, it means *think I* or *I think*. I don't see any reason that this usage should be in Wiktionary—it's not standard English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Thinks* I** is an example of the historic present tense. This tense is used to add immediacy to the narrative. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present.

**Methinks/methought** seems to have been passing out of the language at the time that Melville wrote, and "**Thinks/Thought I**" seems to be a transitional form.

The third person form of the verb seems to be a colloquialism based on the (lack of) conjugation of "methinks" (impersonal) = "it occur**s** to me."

The commoner form "says he" presents no such problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ishmael is narrating the story sometime afterward.  (We find this out in the first page of the novel.)  So perhaps *thinks I* refers to what Ishmael thinks now (when he is narrating), not what he thought at the time of the story.